# mongo $near command on Nested Array

Tags: java, mongodb

```
{

"merchantId" : "M168976258",
"catalogTypeId" : "catalogTypeProduct",
"items" : [
    {
            "name" : "Product 1",
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    },
    {

            "name" : "Product 2",
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    },
    {
            "name" : "Product 3",
        "location" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                0,
                0
            ]
        }
    }


    }
```

I able to Perfrom mongo near command on document which is having single location
using below command

```
db.abc.find({ 
location :{
  $near : {
  $geometry : {   
     index : "Point" ,
     coordinates : [19.1, 72.89]
    },
   $maxDistance : 10000
   }
}
})
```

but i'm not able to perform on document which having nested array can anybody help me out to find out problem

By running this query i get following error

```
db.catalogForAdminAndMerchant.find({ 
"items.location" :{
  $near : {
  $geometry : {   
     index : "Point" ,
     coordinates : [19.1, 72.89]
    },
 $maxDistance : 10000
}
 }
})
```

o/p is

planner returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query

but have created the index

by running db.catalogForAdminAndMerchant.getIndexes() i get

```
/* 1 */
{
"v" : 1,
"key" : {
    "_id" : 1
},
"name" : "_id_",
"ns" : "catalog-db.catalogForAdminAndMerchant"
 },

  /* 2 */
  {
"v" : 1,
"key" : {
    "_fts" : "text",
    "_ftsx" : 1
},
"name" : "CatalogForAdminAndMerchant_TextIndex",
"ns" : "catalog-db.catalogForAdminAndMerchant",
"weights" : {
    "items.name" : 3
},
"default_language" : "english",
"language_override" : "language",
"textIndexVersion" : 3
},

  /* 3 */
{
"v" : 2,
"key" : {
    "address.items[i].location" : "2dsphere"
},
"name" : "address.items[i].location_2dsphere",
"ns" : "catalog-db.catalogForAdminAndMerchant",
"2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
```

}

Comment: Shouldn't it be find({items.$.location.coordinates ... ?

Comment: @Eric Hello thx for your reply can you explain it more

Comment: @Eric it is not working

Comment: Try items.location.coordinates

Comment: @Eric You mean db.abc.find({items.location.coordinates})

Comment: Yes I mean that

Comment: @Eric m getting error can't complie that  and by using above command how i will able to find out nearest lat and longitude

Comment: @Eric i have updated my question please check